# Azure Build Pipeline: Building solution dependencies fails - can't find packages but building csproj dependency files independently works fine

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-devops, nuget

I have a solution with a bunch of different api's in it which reference different dependencies we built in a utilities folder.

In Azure Devops, when I go to build the solution it complains that it can't find the dependencies of those dependencies and fails. Those dependencies are pointing to the same dependencies of the solution which are a few folders up; so the dependency HintPath is `../../packages` as opposed to the solution's dependency HintPath of `./packages`

When I build the csproj files independent of the solution (i.e. not building them as a dependency of the solution) they build just fine and find the packages folder with no issue. Nuget Restore reports no issues and we have checked in the packages to source control so there should not be anything missing. Even if there was, Nuget would restore them if they were missing.

So I'm thinking: When I build the solution and it tries to build the dependencies down below, it's trying to access the packages starting at the solution directory and then going up from there (`master/../../packages/` instead of `utilities/../../packages/`). That folder does not exist which would cause it to fail and makes sense as to why the individual builds of the dependencies works.

Has anyone come across this issue before in Azure Dev Ops or has any idea how to fix this?

We could edit the hint paths to point to ./ for the dependencies which has worked but we have a local build we still use for production that doesn't function like that and would break. We're trying to keep these in sync.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was changing the way NuGet packages were stored in the solution. Instead of using packages.config, there's an option in Visual Studio to use PackageReference which is a new way of referencing packages for NuGet. After switching most of our projects to the new way of using NuGet it was able to run and build.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Build Pipeline: Building solution dependencies fails - can't find packages but building csproj dependency files independently works fine

To resolve this issue, you could try to install dependencies of those dependencies to the solution. That because NuGet team deprecated solution level packages in NuGet 3.0:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522

So, we need make sure the all the used packages for the solution in the default packages folder `./packages` instead of the different packages folder.

If above not help you, you could share your project structure in your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried that but it will still complain that it can't find the files. I will need to edit each individual csproj files HintPaths to look at ./packages which is not the way it is done for our on prem stuff so it would be impossible to keep those two code bases in sync. If we switched on prem to that we would have a lot of extra packages folders rather than them all looking at one packages folder source. It's just a lot of extra files that shouldn't be needed